# No output after running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'm struggling here with the db migration for the  [acts_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading).

After generating the migration `rails generate acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration` I proceeded to add the comment table `rake db:migrate`. Nothing happened, no error message, just returned to the regular prompt.

Looking at other response to this problem I tried `rake db:migrate VERSION= # version number`.
Yet here I get an Error response `ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError:`

I must be doing something extremely wrong here since the computer doesn't validate the existence of my comment migration...

**UPDATE from [@Tiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618467/tiago-farias) answer**

Ran `rails generate migration acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration`

I had to manually create the migration by adding [this code](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading/blob/master/lib/generators/acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration/templates/migration.rb) to the migration file. Then, the`db:migration` worked perfectly.

Why wasn't it working in the first place? The  [Documentation](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading/blob/master/lib/generators/acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration/templates/migration.rb)  clearly indicate to run `rails generate acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration`.

Comment: It was a mistake or did you type exactly that? Cause it should be 'rails g migration acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration'

Comment: Typed exactly `rails generate acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration` as indicated in the [migration](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading#migrations) section.

Comment: It could be a problem with the plugin. What version of Rails are you ? Did you run bundle install (kinda stupid question, but I have to ask that =))

Comment: Not a stupid question, you gave me a valuable answer and therefore I will accept your answer as the correct one :)! I use Rails 4 and yes i did run `bundle install`

Comment: Alright! Thanks. But I was trying to figure out why it didn't run the way the page shows... probably a bug between Rails versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a migration for yourself as indicated in the gem's page:

```
rails g migration acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration
```

And paste that to the file:

```
class ActsAsCommentableWithThreadingMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :comments, :force => true do |t|
      t.integer :commentable_id, :default => 0
      t.string :commentable_type
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.string :subject
      t.integer :user_id, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.integer :parent_id, :lft, :rgt
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :comments, :user_id
    add_index :comments, [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :comments
  end
end
```